# How to use HTML input type file as FileField type in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have below code in my DJango template which has div and input type file styled in same way such that when you click on image, upload window will be shown up.

```
<div class="prof" style="background:url(https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2669/5830411257_b21bf9e931_b.jpg);background-size:cover">
<input type="file" id="uploadpic" class="uploadpic" />
</div>
```

**Demo of this :**

http://jsfiddle.net/sathish_opr/s54uxkx9/

My requirement is that can I use the input type file of this template as FileField in Django model, so that upload_to is accessible for this input file html tag.

I'm searching for some working model of similar kind, but couldn't find yet.
How could this be possible ? any suggestions ?

In my **Models.py**

```
class td_profpic(models.Model):
id = models.CharField(max_length=300,blank=True)
propicpath = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name)
class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = "td_profpic"

def get_upload_file_name(instance,filename):
return "%s_%s" % (str(time()).replace('.','_'),filename)
```

How can I relate input type file tag of my Template with the Model field (FileField - propicpath) in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Django ModelForm for this.
Create a form for your Model 'td_profpic' with:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
# import your model from your application

Class td_profpicForm(forms.Form):
model= td_profpic
```

After that import this form in your views:
`from forms import td_profpicForm`
and render it to template by creating a view and send this form as context.
In the Django template render this form as {{ form.as_p }} or {{ form.as_table }} and it will create a form for you automatically with your fields. 
You don't need to create custom fields for yourself then.